# Read barcode scanner entry when focused on button

Tags: c#, event-handling, barcode-scanner

I use a barcode scanner listener using the key-press event as follows (from another post):

```
public Form2() {
     InitializeComponent();
     //
     this.KeyPreview = true;
     this.KeyPress += Form2_KeyPress;
     this.Button1_click += (s, e) => {
           // --- even if I don't close the form, the click event firing
           // prevents the "Process barcode" to execute...
           //this.Close();
           Console.Writeln("hitting focused button.");
      }
 }
 public void KeyPress_scanner_preview(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
      // check timing (keystrokes within 100 ms)
      TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
      if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
        _barcode.Clear();

      // record keystroke & timestamp
      _barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
      _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

      // process barcode
      if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0) {
        string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show("Read barcode: " + new String(_barcode.ToArray()));
        _barcode.Clear();
      }
    }
```

Now my problem is that, with my scanner, when I have focus on a button, the "button_click" event fires **BEFORE** the `BarCodeScanned`is fired.

Any hint as to how to prevent this to happen? Possibly disable the button?

EDIT: I added the button click event handler and the form's constructor. Note that I have a single button on the for itself, which is hence automatically focused. Firing the "button click" event prevents the barcode event to be fired (here, showing a messagebox). Note that whether I register the button click event or not doesn't make any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reformat [TaW's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) answer to reflect the case that hitting "Enter" should NOT fire an empty barcode scanned event.

**NOTE** With the original parameters, I was able to fire the barcode scanned event from the keayboard quite easily. I therefore reduced the elapsed typing time to 50ms and made sure the `_barcode` was at least 7 charactes long. This is ok with EAN-8 and EAN-13 formats. Even using both hands, I wasn't able to erroneously fire a barcode saneed event.

**UPDATE** the logic was wrong as the `ProcessCmdKey` should return `true` if the event key is handled. I implemented the logic in the updated code.

Here the code:

```
DateTime _lastKeystroke = new DateTime(0);
string _barcode = string.Empty;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    bool res = processKey(keyData);
    return keyData == Keys.Enter ? res : base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

bool processKey(Keys key)
{
    // check timing (>7 keystrokes within 50 ms)
    TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
    if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 50)
    {
        _barcode = string.Emtpy;
    }
    // record keystroke & timestamp
    _barcode += (char)key;
    _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;
    // process barcode
    // --- barcode length should be > 1, not 0 (as the return char
    // itself was added above)
    if (key == Keys.Enter && _barcode.Length > 1)
    {
        string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
        _barcode = string.Empty;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the focus back to the target when necessary.

You don't show enough code to cover all bases but this should give you the idea:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do the real click work..:

    // then reset the focus
    resetFocus();
}

void resetFocus() // rest focus to a textbox and clear the selection
{
    textBox1.Focus();
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

**Update 1:**

If your `Button` didn't receive the focus because it was **pressed** but because **nothing else can receive focus** you can workaround by adding `PreviewKeyPress` events to Form **and** Button. Set `Form.KeyPreview=true` !

**Update 2:**
If you have many Buttons and other things you still can workaround by overriding  `ProcessCmdKey`. The regular way to use `PreviewKeyDown` on the form only will not work as `Buttons` steal the `Enter`key before it gets handed down.. No need to set the `Form.KeyPreview` now.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        processKey((char) keyData);  // we need the Enter key
        return false;                // do not steal it!
    }
    processKey((char)keyData);       // process other keys
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

For this move the code that processes the keystrokes into a function:

```
void processKey(Keys key)
{

    // check timing (keystrokes within 100 ms)
    TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
    if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
        _barcode = ""; // Clear();

    // record keystroke & timestamp
    _barcode += (char)key; // e.KeyChar);
    _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;

    // process barcode

    if (key == Keys.Enter && _barcode.Length > 0)
    {
        string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
        if (BarCodeScanned != null)
        {
            BarCodeScanned(sender, 
                           new BarcodeScannedEventArgs(new String(_barcode.ToArray())));
        }

        BarCodeScanned(_barcode);
        _barcode.Clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer; please see if that suits your needs better.. Dod check if the space key still can press the button!

Comment: Thanks, it works. As a side question: how how can I make this "generic", assuming I don't know which button has focus and I want my whole form to react first to the barcode entry? Do I have to register "preview_key" for all buttons when I focus on them? Isn't there another way?